# How can I tell if port 465 is open for outbound traffic?

Tags: amazon-ec2, smtp

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 server set up on AWS EC2. I'm trying to configure Railo to use Simple Email Service (SES) via an SMTP call (see "[Sending Email with the new SMTP Support for Amazon SES](http://www.anujgakhar.com/2011/12/14/sending-email-with-the-new-smtp-support-for-amazon-ses/)" for specifics). I've gone through the SES steps to verify senders/receivers and applied the relevant code.

Attempted mails are not getting through. When I look at the Railo email logs I see "javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException". I suspect that port 465 is not allowing outbound traffic. How can I

1. determine if port 465 is open for outbound traffic, and
2. open port 465 for outbound traffic if it isn't already?

The AWS security profile seems to me to be inbound-centric–so I don't think there's anything there to configure (but please alert me if there is).

Comment: OP figured out how to make it work, but forgot how, per comment.

Comment: Also, javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException does not suggest a blocked outbound port to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outgoing ports are always open on EC2. It might be a different error, try setting mail.debug to true and run the program. Logs generated will be very helpful in determining the root cause.

Comment: I'm embarrased--I figured out how to make it work, but it's been so long that I don't know what I did so I can't leave the answer here for others.